# Automating Download of Site Dynamically generated http file

Tags: .net, powershell

I am trying to automate the download of report http://www.wesm.ph. However, the page generates the file on demand and the download URL will generate something like this:

http://www.wesm.ph/download.php?download=TUJBT1JURF8yMDE3LTA3LTI2XzIwMTctMDctMjZfR19MVVpPTi5jc3Y=

Is it possible to automate this? Thank you.

Comment: The above `download` parameter is a Base64-encoded string. This decodes to `MBAORTD_2017-07-26_2017-07-26_G_LUZON.csv`. Assuming that you **know** exactly what the target files are going to be, then yes, it would be possible to build a script to encode the target file as Base64 and then affix it to the URL :)

Comment: Sorry, I am quite new with this but how do I do this? I suppose the parameter building will be the most challenging part of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will grab the latest file.

Set $folderPath to the folder where the CSV's are saved.

```
$folderPath = 'C:\Users\Michael\Downloads'

# If I can't download something from the last two weeks 
# then use this flag to track the error. 
$downloadSucceeded = $false

function giveBinaryEqualFile ([string] $myInput, [string] $fileName)
{
    $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($fileName, $myInput, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
}

function generateAddress ([DateTime] $myDate)
{
    $localTimeZone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local
    $PhilippineTimeZone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("China Standard Time")

    $PhilippineNow = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTime($myDate, $localTimeZone, $PhilippineTimeZone)

    # Address
    $address = "http://www.wesm.ph/download.php?download="

    # What is the file name? 
    $dateInName = Get-Date -Date $PhilippineNow -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    $nameInURL = "MBAORTD_{0}_{0}_G_LUZON.csv" -f $dateInName
    $fileName  =     "RTD_{0}_{0}_G_LUZON.csv" -f $dateInName

    # Base64 Encode
    $byteArray = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($nameInURL)
    $encodedFileName = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($byteArray)

    # URL
    $url = $address + $encodedFileName

    # Object 
    $properties = @{
        'address'  = $url
        'fileName' = $fileName
    }

    New-Object PSObject -Property $properties
}


# Try to download the latest file. 
# Search the last two weeks. 
:latest for($i=0; $i -ge -14; $i--)
{
    $localNow = (Get-Date).AddDays($i)
    $name = generateAddress $localNow
    $myRequest = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $name.address

    # Skip this URL if the file length is zero. 
    if ($myRequest.RawContentLength -eq 0)
    {  continue latest  }

    # Skip this URL if we get the 404 page. 
    foreach ($element in $myRequest.AllElements) 
    {   
        if ($element.class -eq 'error')
        {  continue latest  }
    }

    # We did not see an error message. 
    # We must have the file. 

    # Save the file. 
    $myPath = Join-Path $folderPath ($name.fileName)
    if (Test-Path -Path $myPath )
    {
        Write-Host "$($name.fileName) already exists. Exiting. "
        exit
    }
    else
    {  giveBinaryEqualFile ($myRequest.Content) $myPath  }

    # Record success. 
    $downloadSucceeded = $true

    # Leave the loop. 
    break latest
}

if ($downloadSucceeded)
{
    Write-Host "The download succeeded."
    Write-Host "File Name: $($name.fileName)"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "The download failed."
    Write-Host "No files available from the last two weeks. "
}
```

Downloading the file using a Web browser and downloading using a HtmlWebResponseObject produce different files. The content is the same. But the encoding differs. And PowerShell formatters add a newline. So I [Removed the BOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596982/using-powershell-to-write-a-file-in-utf-8-without-the-bom#5596984) and [newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279848/prevent-trailing-newline-in-powershell-out-file-command#35279910). And you can reuse my giveBinaryEqualFile() function to fix formatting problems in other scripts.

Make sure we're using the Philippine [time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649055/create-datetime-object-of-other-timezone-in-powershell/20101121#20101121). [Another example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).

[Encode the URL](http://blogs.metcorpconsulting.com/tech/?p=1325) per Obsidian Age's comment.

And use [labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Break) to break out of loops early.

Comment: Wow, this just works perfectly. I just need to adjust the date since the report is delayed by around a week. Thank you very much!

Comment: No adjustment needed. I noticed that this would get the latest files from the last two weeks. You're the real MVP!